# Breeze Complex Types Data Properties Shows No Data

Tags: breeze

I am using the Breeze Edmunds as an example.

As you can see below I have added a new **names** data property on the Make entity as a complex type. The complex type is shown at the bottom of the initialize function.

After calling the web api and results are returned I see the new data property on the make results but there is no data for this new names. Shown Below:

```
Array[61]
0: proto._setCtor.proto
_backingStore: Object
entityAspect: ctor
id: (...)
modelLinks: (...)
models: (...)
name: "AM General"
**names**: proto._setCtor.proto
_backingStore: Object
complexAspect: ctor
name: ""
__proto__: Object
niceName: (...)
__proto__: Object
1: proto._setCtor.proto
2: proto._setCtor.proto
3: proto._setCtor.proto
4: proto._setCtor.proto
5: proto._setCtor.proto
6: proto._setCtor.proto
7: proto._setCtor.proto
8: proto._setCtor.proto
9: proto._setCtor.proto
10: proto._setCtor.proto
11: proto._setCtor.proto
12: proto._setCtor.proto
13: proto._setCtor.proto
14: proto._setCtor.proto
15: proto._setCtor.proto
16: proto._setCtor.proto
17: proto._setCtor.proto
18: proto._setCtor.proto
19: proto._setCtor.proto
20: proto._setCtor.proto
21: proto._setCtor.proto
22: proto._setCtor.proto
23: proto._setCtor.proto
24: proto._setCtor.proto
25: proto._setCtor.proto
26: proto._setCtor.proto
27: proto._setCtor.proto
28: proto._setCtor.proto
29: proto._setCtor.proto
30: proto._setCtor.proto
31: proto._setCtor.proto
32: proto._setCtor.proto
33: proto._setCtor.proto
34: proto._setCtor.proto
35: proto._setCtor.proto
36: proto._setCtor.proto
37: proto._setCtor.proto
38: proto._setCtor.proto
39: proto._setCtor.proto
40: proto._setCtor.proto
41: proto._setCtor.proto
42: proto._setCtor.proto
43: proto._setCtor.proto
44: proto._setCtor.proto
45: proto._setCtor.proto
46: proto._setCtor.proto
47: proto._setCtor.proto
48: proto._setCtor.proto
49: proto._setCtor.proto
50: proto._setCtor.proto
51: proto._setCtor.proto
52: proto._setCtor.proto
53: proto._setCtor.proto
54: proto._setCtor.proto
55: proto._setCtor.proto
56: proto._setCtor.proto
57: proto._setCtor.proto
58: proto._setCtor.proto
59: proto._setCtor.proto
60: proto._setCtor.proto
length: 61
__proto__: Array[0]
```

What I am missing?

Thanks...

```
    metadataStore.addEntityType({
        shortName: "Make",
        namespace: "Edmunds",
        dataProperties: {
            id:         { dataType: DT.Int64, isPartOfKey: true },
            name: { dataType: DT.String },
            names: { dataType: DT.ComplexType, complexTypeName: "Names:#Edmunds", isScalar: true },
            niceName:   { dataType: DT.String },
            modelLinks: { dataType: DT.Undefined }
        },
        navigationProperties: {
            models: {
                entityTypeName:  "Model:#Edmunds", isScalar: false,
                associationName: "Make_Models"
            }
        }
    });

    metadataStore.addEntityType({
        shortName: "Names",
        namespace: "Edmunds",
        isComplexType: true,
        dataProperties: {
            name: { dataType: DT.String, isNullable: false }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change the metadata in this sample you will need to change the 'jsonResultsAdapter' code as well.

Comment: I made the following change with affect

Comment: Not sure I understand your comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
I added the complex type as well as the undefined type and as you can there is no data resturned in the complexy type but the undefined type returned fine.

Model Changes

    function initialize(metadataStore) {
            metadataStore.addEntityType({
                shortName: "Make",
                namespace: "Edmunds",
                dataProperties: {
                    id: { dataType: DT.Int64, isPartOfKey: true },
                    modelList: { dataType: DT.ComplexType, complexTypeName: "ModelList:#Edmunds", isScalar: true },
                    name: { dataType: DT.String },
                    niceName:   { dataType: DT.String },
                    modelLinks: { dataType: DT.Undefined }
                }
                //navigationProperties: {
                //    models: {
                //        entityTypeName:  "Model:#Edmunds", isScalar: false,
                //        associationName: "Make_Models"
                //    }
                //}
            });


This is my jsonResultsAdapter code

visitNode: function (node, parseContext, nodeContext) {
            // Make parser
            if (node.id && node.models) {
                // move 'node.models' links so 'models' can be empty array
                modelList = node.models;
                node.modelLinks = node.models;
                //node.models = [];
                return { entityType: "Make"  }
            }

            // Model parser
            else if (node.id && node.makeId) {
                // move 'node.make' link so 'make' can be null reference
                node.makeLink = node.make;
                node.make = null;

                // flatten styles and sizes as comma-separated strings
                var styles = node.categories && node.categories["Vehicle Style"];
                node.vehicleStyles = styles && styles.join(", ");
                var sizes = node.categories && node.categories["Vehicle Size"];
                node.vehicleSizes = sizes && sizes.join(", ");

                return { entityType: "Model" };
            }


This is the results
```

The undefined type shows data with array[1] while complex type shows data has null values and is proto._setCtor.proto

```
This is the JSON
```

{"makeHolder":[{"id":200347864,"models":[{"link":"/api/vehicle/am-general/hummer","id":"AM_General_Hummer","name":"Hummer"}],"name":"AM General","niceName":"amgeneral","manufacturer":null,"attributeGroups":{}}]}